# Spatie Laravel-activitylog problem with relationship

Tags: laravel, spatie-activitylog

I'm using Laravel 10 and Laravel-activitylog with PHP 8.1

I have a problem when I do `$post->comments()->create([...]);`, it doesn't create the activity log.

I need to do:

```
Comment::create([
 'post_id' => $post->id,
  ... 
]);
```

Exist a way to avoid it and start saving activity from relationship like BelongTo, ManyToMany, etc?

Thanks

Comment: To be clear: You're using the "model events" feature? https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/advanced-usage/logging-model-events

Comment: @ceejayoz Yup. i'm using that